# Loading Custom Fonts over HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: html, css, http, fonts, https

I am loading a custom font in the header as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//example.com/stylesheets/custom-font.css"/>
```

in THAT stylesheet I have ONE block of CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'soneregular';
    src: url('//example.com/fonts/webfont.eot');
    src: url('//example.com/fonts/webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('//example.com/fonts/webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('//example.com/fonts/webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('//example.com/fonts/webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('//example.com/fonts/webfont.svg#soneregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

When I have a page loading via HTTP, the custom fonts load fine, but when the page is loaded via HTTPS, is reverts to a fallback font (sans-serif) and displays these errors in the console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/ecom/myAccount/myAccount.do?forward=/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://example.com/fonts/webfont.woff2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/ecom/myAccount/myAccount.do?forward=/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://example.com/fonts/webfont.woff'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/ecom/myAccount/myAccount.do?forward=/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://example.com/fonts/webfont.ttf'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

What do I need to do to get these custom fonts to load correctly over HTTP AND HTTPS?

Comment: I'm not good at this but I think you need to look at how your server responds to the requests for the fonts, if your website runs https you'll need to make sure your assets are served over https as well, maybe your server decides to default to http when there is no protocol specified as with `//address.com`

Comment: oh - and below is an answer referring to a specific server configuration, if you could atleast share the name of the server software you're using `apache` or `nginx` for example other folks can help you out better :)

Answer (score 0):

Try unsetting the `vary` header for this file type. If you use other filetypes too then also do the same for them.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(woff)$">
    Header unset Vary
</FilesMatch>
```